# proper way to set python logging level?

Tags: python, logging

this is my python file for setting my logging level

```
import datetime
import logging
import pytz
import sys


class LoggerWriter:
    def __init__(self, logger, level):
        self.logger = logger
        self.level = level

    def write(self, message):
        if message != '\n':
            self.logger.log(self.level, message)

    def flush(self):
        pass


def initialize_logger():
    # setting up log requirements
    logger = logging.getLogger('csss_site')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s = %(levelname)s - %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    sys.stdout = LoggerWriter(logger, logging.INFO)
    sys.stderr = LoggerWriter(logger, logging.WARNING)
    create_log_file(formatter, logger)
    return logger


def create_log_file(formatter, logger):
    date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')).strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
    filename = "logs/{}_csss_site".format(date)
    filehandler = logging.FileHandler("{}.log".format(filename))
    filehandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(filehandler)
```

what I basically want from it is

1. all output from `stdout` and `stderr` go into the log file
2. to see everything from `DEBUG` level and higher

I call the function by doing

```
logger = initialize_logger()
```

however, if I use this setup *and* also use the command `python3.7 manage.py getmail` that comes with [django_mailbox](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/django-mailbox), I was getting this output

```
(envCSSS) csss@csss-website:~/csss-site-in-dev/csss-site/src$ python3.7 manage.py getmail
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] BASE_DIR set to /home/csss
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] DEBUG set to True
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] ROOT_DIR set to /home/csss/csss-site-in-dev
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] STATIC_URL set to /STATIC_URL/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] STATIC_ROOT set to /home/csss/static_root/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] MEDIA_URL set to /MEDIA_URL/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] MEDIA_ROOT set to /home/csss/media_root/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] FILE_FORM_MASTER_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] FILE_FORM_UPLOAD_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/temporary_files/
2020-01-14 18:24:56 = INFO - [settings.py] DJANGO_MAILBOX_ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_TO set to mailbox_attachments/%Y/%m/%d/
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:INFO:django_mailbox.management.commands.getmail:Gathering messages for csss gmail
.....................
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-14 10:24:57 = WARNING - WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:WARNING:csss_site:Traceback (most recent call last):
```

but, if I switch to using `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` instead of `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`, that issue stops but what starts happening is duplicate log lines like this

```
/home/modernNeo/virtualenvs/envCSSS/bin/python3.7 /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/csss-site/src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] BASE_DIR set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] BASE_DIR set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] DEBUG set to True
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] DEBUG set to True
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] ENVIRONMENT set to LOCALHOST
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] ENVIRONMENT set to LOCALHOST
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] PORT set to 8000
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] PORT set to 8000
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] HOST_ADDRESS set to 127.0.0.1
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] HOST_ADDRESS set to 127.0.0.1
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] ALLOWED_HOSTS set to ['127.0.0.1']
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] ALLOWED_HOSTS set to ['127.0.0.1']
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] DB_TYPE set to postgres
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] DB_TYPE set to postgres
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] BRANCH_NAME set to None
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] BRANCH_NAME set to None
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] URL_ROOT set to /
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] URL_ROOT set to /
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] URL_PATTERN set to 
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] URL_PATTERN set to 
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] STATICFILES_DIRS=['/home/modernNeo/NAS_Files/Git/CSSS/exec-photos']
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] STATICFILES_DIRS=['/home/modernNeo/NAS_Files/Git/CSSS/exec-photos']
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] ROOT_DIR set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] ROOT_DIR set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] STATIC_URL set to /STATIC_URL/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] STATIC_URL set to /STATIC_URL/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] STATIC_ROOT set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/static_root/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] STATIC_ROOT set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/static_root/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] MEDIA_URL set to /MEDIA_URL/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] MEDIA_URL set to /MEDIA_URL/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] MEDIA_ROOT set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/media_root/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] MEDIA_ROOT set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/media_root/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] FILE_FORM_MASTER_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] FILE_FORM_MASTER_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] FILE_FORM_UPLOAD_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/temporary_files/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] FILE_FORM_UPLOAD_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/temporary_files/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] DJANGO_MAILBOX_ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_TO set to mailbox_attachments/%Y/%m/%d/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] DJANGO_MAILBOX_ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_TO set to mailbox_attachments/%Y/%m/%d/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] BASE_DIR set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] BASE_DIR set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] DEBUG set to True
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] DEBUG set to True
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] ENVIRONMENT set to LOCALHOST
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] ENVIRONMENT set to LOCALHOST
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] PORT set to 8000
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] PORT set to 8000
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] HOST_ADDRESS set to 127.0.0.1
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] HOST_ADDRESS set to 127.0.0.1
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] ALLOWED_HOSTS set to ['127.0.0.1']
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] ALLOWED_HOSTS set to ['127.0.0.1']
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] DB_TYPE set to postgres
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] DB_TYPE set to postgres
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] BRANCH_NAME set to None
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] BRANCH_NAME set to None
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] URL_ROOT set to /
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] URL_ROOT set to /
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] URL_PATTERN set to 
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] URL_PATTERN set to 
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] STATICFILES_DIRS=['/home/modernNeo/NAS_Files/Git/CSSS/exec-photos']
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] STATICFILES_DIRS=['/home/modernNeo/NAS_Files/Git/CSSS/exec-photos']
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] ROOT_DIR set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] ROOT_DIR set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] STATIC_URL set to /STATIC_URL/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] STATIC_URL set to /STATIC_URL/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] STATIC_ROOT set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/static_root/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] STATIC_ROOT set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/static_root/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] MEDIA_URL set to /MEDIA_URL/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] MEDIA_URL set to /MEDIA_URL/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] MEDIA_ROOT set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/media_root/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] MEDIA_ROOT set to /media/modernNeo/modernNeo_usb_1/csss-site/media_root/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] FILE_FORM_MASTER_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] FILE_FORM_MASTER_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] FILE_FORM_UPLOAD_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/temporary_files/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] FILE_FORM_UPLOAD_DIR set to form_uploads/form_uploads/temporary_files/
2020-10-02 19:53:31 = INFO - [settings.py] DJANGO_MAILBOX_ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_TO set to mailbox_attachments/%Y/%m/%d/
INFO:csss_site:[settings.py] DJANGO_MAILBOX_ATTACHMENT_UPLOAD_TO set to mailbox_attachments/%Y/%m/%d/
2020-10-02 19:53:32 = WARNING - Watching for file changes with StatReloader

WARNING:csss_site:Watching for file changes with StatReloader

INFO:django.utils.autoreload:Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2020-10-02 19:53:32 = INFO - Performing system checks...


INFO:csss_site:Performing system checks...


2020-10-02 19:53:32 = INFO - System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

INFO:csss_site:System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

2020-10-02 19:53:32 = INFO - October 02, 2020 - 19:53:32

INFO:csss_site:October 02, 2020 - 19:53:32

2020-10-02 19:53:32 = INFO - Django version 2.2.13, using settings 'csss.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

INFO:csss_site:Django version 2.2.13, using settings 'csss.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Am I setting up my logging wrong or is `django_mailbox` at fault?

Answer (score 0):

For the second case, here is what happens.

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` call adds a `StreamHandler` to the `root` logger if it hasn't had any handler. This handler writes to `stderr` as default.

Your logger doesn't define `propagate=False`, so any record handled by your logger is propagated to the `root` logger and is written out to `stderr` again with a different format. Thus, you saw duplication of every log message.

For the first case, a quick look into `django_mailbox` code showed that it calls `basicConfig` in [getmail.py](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/django-mailbox/blob/master/django_mailbox/management/commands/getmail.py), too. Since you replaced `stderr` with your `LoggerWriter` class, log messages, which are written to `stderr`, are passed to your logger. That explains the `WARNING` text.

Then, the same as the second case, they are also propagated to the `root` logger which also writes to `stderror`. This is where the loop happens.

---

> all output from stdout and stderr go into the log file

I get it. But let me rephrase what you want:

*log all output and exception's **traceback** of the program in a **simple** way.*

If the word **simple** matches your expectation, then you may try [logger-tt](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt) package.

```
from logger_tt import setup_logging
from logging import getLogger
# import other stuff

setup_logging(capture_print=True)    # config all loggers and capture msg from print(msg)
logger = getLogger(__name__)         # logger for this .py file only

# your code below
```

That's it. It gives you a time rotated log file with the `DEBUG` level and a stream to `stdout` with the `INFO` level. All just work like magic!

Comment: thanks. still got some lingering questions that i hope you can clear up.

"Your logger doesn't define propagate=False, so any record handled by your logger is propagated to the root logger and is written out to stderr again with a different format. Thus, you saw duplication of every log message." So, if I understand you correctly, the default logging level for the `root` handler is `INFO` and by setting it to `DEBUG`, that meant that not only was the custom logger that I had defined printing out the logs, but the `root` also was printing them out?

Comment: but that does not make sense because I used `logger.info` for all my log lines and not `logger.debug`. I would think that setting the `root` handler to debug would result in duplicate lines if I had used `logger.debug` which would mean both my logger and the `root` logger would print out the same lines?

Comment: @modernNeo Yes, your logger and the root logger also printing out message.

Comment: @modernNeo logger filters messages by level priority. When a logger was set to DEBUG level, every message whose level bigger than DEBUG is processed. The order are NOTSET < DEBUG < INFO < WARNING < ERROR < CRITICAL. They are all just integer number. You could even add your own level in between.

Comment: @dragonfly but my confusion comes from the fact that the logger level I use is `logger.info` when printing out any log lines. given that, shouldn't there be duplicate logs from my logger and `root` even if the log level for `root` is `INFO` because both would be printing out `INFO` level and that is the level I use for all my logging.

Comment: @modernNeo Which case of the code in the question are you talking about? If `logging.basicConfig()` is not called, there is no handler in the `root` to print the log out.

Comment: @dragonfly oh, I was under the incorrect assumption that `root` has a default handler that is at level `INFO` **before** I set it to `DEBUG`

Comment: @dragongfly, not quite.

Comment: I now understand why the second case with the duplication was happening, but now I am trying to understand what was going on with the first case.

Comment: So as far as I can tell, and based on your explanation so far, I was setting the default logging level for my logger to `DEBUG` and then ensuring that `sys.stdout` get directed to my logger at level `INFO` and `sys.stderr` get directed to my logger at level `WARNING`.

Comment: And I was also setting it up so that all logs at level `INFO` or higher also get directed to the file. Furthermore, since the django mailbox was experiencing an error, that is where the `WARNING` in the log file came from since `sys.stderr` -> `WARNING`

Comment: But I still do not understand how al of that lead to the repetition I see in the logs where it just keeps printing out the previous statement with another `WARNING` attached to the front.

Comment: @modernNeo You replaced `stderr` with your logger. `mailbox` logger logs the message. Since this logger has no handler, it does nothing except propagating the message to the `root` logger.  After `basicConfig`, `root` logger has a handler that writes to `stderr`,  your logger for precisely.

Comment: @modernNeo Your logger holds the real `stderr` stream, so it writes the formatted message from the `root` logger out. Since your logger is a child logger, it also propagates that message back to the `root` logger. The loop begins with the new formatted message. That is why `WARNING` keeps being appended to the new logline.

Comment: @dragonfly, sorry, but I need a clarification on your first message. you said "After `basicConfig`, `root` logger has a handler that writes to `stderr`, your logger for precisely."

Comment: You are saying that the line calling `basicConfig` in the `django_mailbox` gives the `root` a handler that write to `stderr`, which to be specific, is the handler I created for my logger?

Comment: @modernNeo yes. Because there is no handler attached to the `root` logger, `basicConfig` add a `streamHandler`, which writes to `stderr`, to the root. But you already replaced it by `LoggerWriter`, your logger, this means handler of the root will write to your logger.

Comment: @dragonfly, the line django_mailbox that does the logging setup is `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`.

Comment: you are saying that that results in [1] settings the logging level for `root` handler to `INFO` and [2] ensures that any output from root that is level `INFO` or above writes to `stderr` [which I had already replaced with my logger at level `WARNING`]?

Comment: @modernNeo Yes.